# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 2(offset:2).state:20

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

This problem appears often in my project, but I can't find the reason. Please, give me some advice.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 2(offset:2).state:20

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 2(offset:2).state:20
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java)
at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.add(GapWorker.java)
                                       postFromTraversal(GapWorker.java)
                                       buildTaskList(GapWorker.java)
                                       isPrefetchPositionAttached(GapWorker.java)
                                       prefetchPositionWithDeadline(GapWorker.java)
                                       prefetchInnerRecyclerViewWithDeadline(GapWorker.java)
                                       flushTaskWithDeadline(GapWorker.java)
                                       prefetch(GapWorker.java)
at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.add(GapWorker.java)
                                       postFromTraversal(GapWorker.java)
                                       buildTaskList(GapWorker.java)
                                       isPrefetchPositionAttached(GapWorker.java)
                                       prefetchPositionWithDeadline(GapWorker.java)
                                       prefetchInnerRecyclerViewWithDeadline(GapWorker.java)
                                       flushTaskWithDeadline(GapWorker.java)
                                       prefetch(GapWorker.java)
at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.remove(GapWorker.java)
                                       flushTasksWithDeadline(GapWorker.java)
at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.add(GapWorker.java)
                                       postFromTraversal(GapWorker.java)
                                       buildTaskList(GapWorker.java)
                                       isPrefetchPositionAttached(GapWorker.java)
                                       prefetchPositionWithDeadline(GapWorker.java)
                                       prefetchInnerRecyclerViewWithDeadline(GapWorker.java)
                                       flushTaskWithDeadline(GapWorker.java)
                                       prefetch(GapWorker.java)
at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.run(GapWorker.java)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5896)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
```

Code.

```
public class DuoBeiClassIntermediary implements IRecyclerViewIntermediary {

private List<ClassRoom> mClassRooms;
private Context context;
private Bus mBus;
private String isExpired;
private String courseName;

public DuoBeiClassIntermediary(Context context, List<ClassRoom> classRooms, String isExpired, String courseName) {
    mClassRooms = classRooms;
    this.context = context;
    this.isExpired = isExpired;
    this.courseName = courseName;
    mBus = AppContext.getInstance().getBus();
    mBus.register(this);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mClassRooms.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mClassRooms.get(position);
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int type) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_duobei_class, viewGroup, false);
    return new ClassViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void populateViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    final ClassRoom classRoom = mClassRooms.get(position);
    ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).tvClassNo.setText(position + 1 + "");
    ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).tvClassName.setText(classRoom.getRoomTitle());
    String date = DateUtil.dateToString(DateUtil.StringToDate(classRoom.getStartTime(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"), "MM月dd日");
    String startTime = DateUtil.dateToString(DateUtil.StringToDate(classRoom.getStartTime(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"), "HH:mm");
    String endTime = DateUtil.dateToString(DateUtil.StringToDate(classRoom.getEndTime(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"), "HH:mm");
    ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).btnExercise.setText("课后练习");
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(classRoom.getDownloadVideoDuration())) {
        if (classRoom.getDownloadVideoDuration().contains("'")) {
            ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).tvClassTime.setText(classRoom.getDownloadVideoDuration());
        } else {
            ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).tvClassTime.setText(classRoom.getDownloadVideoDuration() + "分钟");
        }
    } else {
        ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).tvClassTime.setText(date + " " + startTime + "-" + endTime);
    }
    if (classRoom.getHasExercise() == 0) {
        ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).btnExercise.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).btnExercise.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    if ("true".equals(classRoom.getShiting())) {
        ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).tvClassTime.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).btnClass.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).downloadLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).btnExercise.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).btnClass.setText("立即观看");
    } else {
        ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).tvClassTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (classRoom.getPayType() == 1) {
            if (classRoom.getLiveType() == 0) {
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).btnExercise.setEnabled(true);
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).btnExercise.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_oval_88);
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).btnExercise.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_88));
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).btnClass.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).btnClass.setText("未直播");
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).btnClass.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_88));
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).btnClass.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_oval_88);
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).btnClass.setEnabled(false);
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).classItem.setEnabled(false);
            } else if (classRoom.getLiveType() == 1) {
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).btnExercise.setEnabled(true);
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).btnExercise.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.course_status_blue_line_bg);
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).btnExercise.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.new_theme_color));
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).btnClass.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).btnClass.setText("正在直播");
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).btnClass.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).btnClass.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.course_status_blue_bg);
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).btnClass.setEnabled(true);
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).classItem.setEnabled(true);
            } else if (classRoom.getLiveType() == 2) {
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).btnExercise.setEnabled(true);
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).btnExercise.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.course_status_blue_line_bg);
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).btnExercise.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.new_theme_color));
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).btnClass.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if (classRoom.getStatus() == Downloads.STATUS_SUCCESS) {
                    ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).btnClass.setText("本地视频");
                } else {
                    ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).btnClass.setText("观看回放");
                }
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).btnClass.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.new_theme_color));
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).btnClass.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.course_status_blue_line_bg);
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).btnClass.setEnabled(true);
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).classItem.setEnabled(true);
            } else if (classRoom.getLiveType() == 3) {
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).btnExercise.setEnabled(true);
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).btnExercise.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_oval_88);
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).btnExercise.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_88));
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).btnClass.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).btnClass.setText("即将直播");
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).btnClass.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.new_theme_color));
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).btnClass.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.course_status_blue_line_bg);
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).btnClass.setEnabled(true);
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).classItem.setEnabled(true);
            }
        } else {
            ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).classItem.setEnabled(false);
            ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).btnClass.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).btnExercise.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
    if (classRoom.getListStatus() == Constants.DuobeiListStatus.DOWNLOAD) {
        //下载view
        ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).btnClass.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).btnExercise.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(classRoom.getDownloadUrl())) {
            Timber.e("status=" + classRoom.getStatus() + ",position=" + position);
            Timber.e("url=" + classRoom.getDownloadUrl() + ",position=" + position);
            //如果存在下载链接,才显示下载按钮
            ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).downloadLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).totalSize.setText(Formatter.formatFileSize(context.getApplicationContext(), classRoom.getDownloadVideoSize()));
            if (classRoom.getCurrentSize() > 0) {
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).currentSize.setText(Formatter.formatFileSize(context.getApplicationContext(), classRoom.getCurrentSize()) + "/");
            }
            if (classRoom.getStatus() == Downloads.STATUS_SUCCESS) {
                //下载成功
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).error.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).downloadStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).progressStatus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).speed.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).currentSize.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).downloadStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_delete_status);
            } else if (classRoom.getStatus() == Downloads.STATUS_WAIT
                    || classRoom.getStatus() == Downloads.STATUS_WAITING_FOR_NETWORK
                    || classRoom.getStatus() == Downloads.STATUS_WAITING_TO_RETRY) {
                //等待状态
                if (classRoom.getCurrentSize() > 0) {
                    ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).currentSize.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).currentSize.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).error.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).downloadStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).progressStatus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).speed.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).downloadStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_wait_status);
            } else if (classRoom.getStatus() == Downloads.STATUS_RUNNING) {
                //正在下载 STATUS_RUNNING 和 CONTROLE_RUN的区别
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).error.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).downloadStatus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).progressStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).speed.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).currentSize.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if (classRoom.getDownloadVideoSize() > 0) {
                    Timber.e("DuobeiClassIntermediary" + classRoom.getCurrentSize() * 100 / classRoom.getDownloadVideoSize());
                    ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).progressStatus.setProgress((int) ((classRoom.getCurrentSize() * 100 / classRoom.getDownloadVideoSize())));
                    ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).currentSize.setText(Formatter.formatFileSize(context.getApplicationContext(), classRoom.getCurrentSize()) + "/");
                    ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).speed.setText(getNetSpeed());
                }
            } else if (classRoom.getStatus() == Downloads.STATUS_FILE_ERROR) {
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).error.setText("下载失败 内存不足");
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).error.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).downloadStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).progressStatus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).speed.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if (classRoom.getCurrentSize() > 0) {
                    ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).currentSize.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).currentSize.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).downloadStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_download_status);
            } else {
                //其他状态,都视为未下载状态
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).error.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).downloadStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).progressStatus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).speed.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if (classRoom.getCurrentSize() > 0) {
                    ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).currentSize.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).currentSize.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).downloadStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_download_status);
            }
        } else {
            ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).downloadLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    } else if (classRoom.getListStatus() == Constants.DuobeiListStatus.NORMAL) {
        //正常view
        ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).downloadLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).btnClass.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if (isExpired == null || !"1".equals(isExpired)) {
            if ("true".equals(classRoom.getShiting())) {
                //试听课
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, DuobeiSampleClassActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("url", classRoom.getVideoUrl());
                intent.putExtra("roomTitle", classRoom.getRoomTitle());
                intent.putExtra("classFlag", 1);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                //课程列表
                if (classRoom.getStatus() == Downloads.STATUS_SUCCESS) {
                    //如果已经是本地视频的话
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, DuobeiSampleClassActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("url", classRoom.getDownloadUrl());
                    intent.putExtra("roomTitle", classRoom.getRoomTitle());
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, DuoBeiClassActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("roomId", classRoom.getRoomId());
                    intent.putExtra("roomTitle", classRoom.getRoomTitle());
                    intent.putExtra("liveType", classRoom.getLiveType());
                    intent.putExtra("startTime", classRoom.getStartTime());
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        } else {
            Utils.showShortToast("课程已过期");
        }
    });
    ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).btnExercise.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        if (isExpired == null || !"1".equals(isExpired)) {
            if (classRoom.getLiveType() == 3 || classRoom.getLiveType() == 0) {
                Utils.showShortToast("课程开始直播后才能进入练习~");
            } else {
                ExerciseListActivity.start(context, classRoom.getRoomId() + "", classRoom.getRoomTitle(), courseName);
                StatisticsUtil.b511(context, courseName, classRoom.getRoomTitle());
            }
        } else {
            Utils.showShortToast("课程已过期");
        }
    });
    ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).classItem.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if (isExpired == null || !"1".equals(isExpired)) {
            if ("true".equals(classRoom.getShiting())) {
                //试听课
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, DuobeiSampleClassActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("url", classRoom.getVideoUrl());
                intent.putExtra("roomTitle", classRoom.getRoomTitle());
                context.startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                //课程列表
                if (classRoom.getStatus() == Downloads.STATUS_SUCCESS) {
                    //如果已经是本地视频的话
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, DuobeiSampleClassActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("url", classRoom.getDownloadUrl());
                    intent.putExtra("roomTitle", classRoom.getRoomTitle());
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, DuoBeiClassActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("roomId", classRoom.getRoomId());
                    intent.putExtra("roomTitle", classRoom.getRoomTitle());
                    intent.putExtra("liveType", classRoom.getLiveType());
                    intent.putExtra("startTime", classRoom.getStartTime());
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        } else {
            Utils.showShortToast("课程已过期");
        }
    });
    ((ClassViewHolder) viewHolder).downloadStatusLayout.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if (isExpired == null || !"1".equals(isExpired)) {
            if (classRoom.getStatus() == Downloads.STATUS_SUCCESS) {
                //下载成功
                showDeleteDialog(classRoom.getDownloadUrl());
            } else if (classRoom.getStatus() == Downloads.STATUS_WAIT) {
                //等待状态从队列中移除url
                List<ClassRoom> classRooms = new ArrayList<>();
                classRooms.add(classRoom);
                mBus.post(new RemoveDownloadUrlEvent(classRooms));
                //更新状态
                new Update(ClassRoom.class).set(ClassTable.COLUMN_STATUS + "=0")
                        .where(ClassTable.COLUMN_DOWNLOADURL + "=?", classRoom.getDownloadUrl())
                        .execute(true);

            } else if (classRoom.getStatus() == Downloads.STATUS_RUNNING) {
                //暂停
                Utils.getDownloadManager().pauseDownload(classRoom.getDownloadId());
            } else if (classRoom.getStatus() == Downloads.STATUS_PAUSED_BY_APP ||
                    classRoom.getStatus() == Downloads.STATUS_WAITING_TO_RETRY ||
                    classRoom.getStatus() == Downloads.STATUS_WAITING_FOR_NETWORK ||
                    classRoom.getStatus() == Downloads.STATUS_QUEUED_FOR_WIFI) {
                //暂停重新开始下载
                List<ClassRoom> classRooms = new ArrayList<>();
                classRooms.add(classRoom);
                mBus.post(new AddDownloadUrlEvent(classRooms));
            } else {
                //未下载
                if (PreferenceUtils.build(context).isDownloadPathOnExternalSd()) {
                    //sdcard1下载
                    if (FileUtil.getSdAvaliableSize() > classRoom.getDownloadVideoSize()) {
                        List<ClassRoom> classRooms = new ArrayList<>();
                        classRooms.add(classRoom);
                        mBus.post(new AddDownloadUrlEvent(classRooms));
                    } else {
                        Utils.showShortToast("剩余空间不足,请清理存储空间或重设下载路径");
                    }
                } else {
                    //sdcard2下载
                    if (FileUtil.getAnotherSdAvaliableSize(context) > classRoom.getDownloadVideoSize()) {
                        List<ClassRoom> classRooms = new ArrayList<>();
                        classRooms.add(classRoom);
                        mBus.post(new AddDownloadUrlEvent(classRooms));
                    } else {
                        Utils.showShortToast("剩余空间不足,请清理存储空间或重设下载路径");
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            Utils.showShortToast("课程已过期");
        }
    });
}

private long lastTotalRxBytes = 0;
private long lastTimeStamp = 0;

private String getNetSpeed() {
    long nowTotalRxBytes = Utils.getTotalRxBytes(context);
    long nowTimeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long speed = 0;
    if (nowTimeStamp - lastTimeStamp != 0) {
        speed = ((nowTotalRxBytes - lastTotalRxBytes) * 1000 / (nowTimeStamp - lastTimeStamp));
    }
    lastTimeStamp = nowTimeStamp;
    lastTotalRxBytes = nowTotalRxBytes;
    return String.valueOf(speed) + " kb/s";
}

public void unregister() {
    mBus.unregister(this);
}

private void showDeleteDialog(final String downloadUrl) {
    View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.layout_wifi_switch_dialog, null);
    TextView tip = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_tip);
    final TextView cancel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_cancel);
    TextView commit = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_commit);
    tip.setText("确认删除");
    final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setView(view)
            .setCancelable(true)
            .show();
    cancel.setOnClickListener(v -> dialog.cancel());
    commit.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Utils.deleteFileByUrl(context, downloadUrl);
        new Update(ClassRoom.class).set(ClassTable.COLUMN_STATUS + "=0,"
                + ClassTable.COLUMN_DOWNLOADID + "=0,"
                + ClassTable.COLUMN_CURRENTSIZE + "=0")
                .where(ClassTable.COLUMN_DOWNLOADURL + "=?", downloadUrl)
                .execute(true);
        //如果有文件删除的话,那么就把因内存不足的状态置为0
        new Update(ClassRoom.class).set(ClassTable.COLUMN_STATUS + "=0")
                .where(ClassTable.COLUMN_STATUS + "=?", Downloads.STATUS_FILE_ERROR)
                .execute(true);
        dialog.cancel();
    });
}

static class ClassViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    @Bind(R.id.tv_class_no)
    TextView tvClassNo;
    @Bind(R.id.tv_class_name)
    TextView tvClassName;
    @Bind(R.id.tv_class_time)
    TextView tvClassTime;
    @Bind(R.id.btn_class)
    TextView btnClass;
    @Bind(R.id.item_class)
    LinearLayout classItem;
    @Bind(R.id.downloadStatus)
    ImageView downloadStatus;
    @Bind(R.id.iv_progress_status)
    CircleProgressBar progressStatus;
    @Bind(R.id.download_layout)
    LinearLayout downloadLayout;
    @Bind(R.id.tv_speed)
    TextView speed;
    @Bind(R.id.tv_currentsize)
    TextView currentSize;
    @Bind(R.id.tv_totalsize)
    TextView totalSize;
    @Bind(R.id.download_status_layout)
    FrameLayout downloadStatusLayout;
    @Bind(R.id.tv_error)
    TextView error;
    @Bind(R.id.btn_exercise)
    TextView btnExercise;

    public ClassViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: please explain your problem elaborately enough that we can help you. Please mention what are you trying to do? And when this crash happened?

Comment: @WasimReza i do not know how to happen because I was found in the statistical platform，and there is nothing related to my Activity/Fragment

Comment: please post ur adapter class

Comment: @KiranBennyJoseph Has been posted

Comment: I think you are changing your data set without notifying adapter.